# Is it bad practice to renew an access tokens too often?

Tags: rest, jwt, token

I'm working against a RESTful service that gives me an access token which is valid for an hour. Each time I receive a response from the server, I check if the token has expired and if it has, I renew it and send the request again.

But this got me thinking: what keeps me from getting a new token each time I make a request instead? I would have saved a few lines of codes if I just sent a request for a new token before each request instead of handling the exception when the token actually expire. Are there any technological reasons to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a request on every call it may cause some latency issue. I hour window is really huge, for every request if you make a call you will end up making too many calls just to get a token when what you have was perfectly fine.
Having said that normally Access token are alive for somewhere between 5 to 10 mins (there is nothing wrong if its valid for longer duration but thats not how they meant to be used). You should not wait to get 401 from the server to refresh the token. Rather than even before making a call to server you can check if AT is going to expire in say next 1 minute and if is then you refresh the token.

Adding couple of lines in your code is a great trade off, if you can shave few milliseconds on your request. The time you save stacks up and lowers your latency

What it saves you from is the time you take to fetch an Access token.

Answer (score 3):

> what keeps me from getting a new token each time I make a request instead?

Nothing prevent you from getting a new token on each request. You will save few lines of code but the counterpart is that it will increase the number of requests against the authorization server.

The token you have is supposed to be valid for 1 hour. You don't have to ask if it is still valid on every request. Just use and and when the resource server return a 401 HTTP response, you renew it.